# ASPxGridView change height on resize, possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an ASPxGridView with SettingsPager set as

```
Mode = ShowAllRecords, PageSize = 100000, CurrentPageNumberFormat = '', Visible = False
```

What I want is to have all the records display with a scroll bar and have no page size at all.

When the containing parent DIV tag is resized the Grid should also adjust it's height. Currently, I see a few records, as many as would fit into the size of the parent div. However, when I resize, I still see the same number of records and empty gray portions at the top and bottom. If the grid does not have a pagesize, I should just be able to see the rows below, right?

#### EDIT:

Here's what I've tried -

```
grid.setHeight(newHeight);
grid.AdjustControls();
```

and also the solution mentioned [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E1081.aspx), which works fine to set the initial height.

Comment: Pay attention to a character case: Use the SetHeight() method instead.

Comment: With "GridView.SettingsPager.Mode = DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GridViewPagerMode.ShowAllRecords;" you do not need to set the PageSize since it will not be used.

Answer (score 2):

See [this sample on DevExpress website](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E1081.aspx) to do what you want.

**EDIT:** To do the same thing when resizing the containing `div`, rather than just the browser window, change the JavaScript code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function adjustSize(newHeight) {
        grid.SetHeight(newHeight);
    }
</script>
```

Then, in the JavaScript that resizes the height of the container div, call `adjustSize(newHeight)` to adjust the size of the grid to match.

Or, more simply, just call `grid.SetHeight(whateverSize)` in the same block of JavaScript you use to resize the `div`.

Comment: This only sets the height on init, I want the height to adjust on resize as well

Comment: That code handles the window resize event. I will be resizing the parent "DIV" tag that contains this grid, I already have this code to handle the initial height, and this does not help resize the grid on the "DIV" resize

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to specify/correct the Height on:

- Control Init;
- Window Resize.

Use recomendations from the following examples to accomplish this task:

[How to use the ASPxPageControl control in a Full Screen mode](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E3940.aspx)

[Change the VerticalScrollableHeight on the client based on the browser window height](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E1081.aspx)